# SSIS Error 0xC001000E at Package: Thrown by connection collection when the specific element is not found

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, business-intelligence

I am getting the above error in a Bulk Insert Task Editor in SSIS in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 using Business Intelligence.

```
SSIS Error 0xC001000E at Package: Thrown by connection collection when the specific element is not found
The connection "C:\Temp\Objects.bin" is not found. 
Error: 0xC002F304 at Bulk Insert Task, Bulk Insert Task: An error occurred   with the following error message: 
"Cannot bulk load because the file   "C:\Temp\objects.bin" could not be opened. 
Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).".
```

As you can see by the xml of the package is exists(objects.bin) and I have selected this file for the source connection. The file definitely exists and I have tried it as a different file type(.txt) as well. I do not understand why I am getting the error.

Package.dtsx(XML)

```
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="DelayValidation">0</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">objects.bin</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="DTSID">{34E3EEA5-9B40-4B25-9DE7-48B0D14346FE}       </DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="Description"></DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="CreationName">FILE</DTS:Property><DTS:ObjectData>     <DTS:ConnectionManager>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="FileUsageType">1</DTS:Property>
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConnectionString">C:\Temp\objects.bin</DTS:Property>  </DTS:ConnectionManager></DTS:ObjectData></DTS:ConnectionManager>
<DTS:ConnectionManager>
```

Bulk Insert Task Editor

[image: Bulk Insert Task Editor Image]

Comment: The first error: "Thrown by connection collection when the specific element is not found
The connection "C:\Temp\Objects.bin" is not found. " implies that it can't even find the connection manager on your package. Make sure that the linkage between your bulk insert task and the connection manager is valid. It's saying it can't find a connection manager called "C:\Temp\Objects.bin" but the connection manager in your screenshot is called"objects.bin". How are you running this - interactively in BIDS or deployed to the server?

Comment: I had the objects.bin file on my local machine and the table to write to on the server. I believe if they are on the same machine the problem is solved. Am I right?

Comment: Quite possibly. If you can test it and confirm it you can accept your answer.

Comment: Yeah it works. Tested and working fine. Thanks.

Comment: You should tick your answer as correct

Comment: I tried. It says that I have to wait 2 days to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bulk copy needs the files it is reading from to be on the same as the server in is writing to. Pretty simple. So now that  sql server destination and the connection files for the source are on the same server the problem is solved.

I should add that I also got into trouble by copying my bulk insert and then trying to change the connection file property. It was impossible to change it after that. That problem was solved after deleting and creating new Bulk Inserts.